# Find conditions syntax in Rails 5.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am upgrading an old RoR app to Rails 5.2.3 and would like know the right syntax for below line in 5.2.3:

```
    default :to => User.find(:all, :conditions => ["admin=?", true]).map(&:email_addr), :from => "foo@grbx.com"
```

Error I am getting is:

```
    Error: The application encountered the following error: Couldn't find all Users with 'id': (all, {:conditions=>["admin=?", true]}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2). (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
User.where(admin: true).pluck(:email_addr)
```

Comment: Or just `User.where(admin: true).pluck(:email_addr)`  ;-)

Comment: Right. Edited it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
`
User.find(:all, :conditions => ["admin=?", true]).map(&:email_addr)
` 

The above command is deprecated in rails 4,5.
You can use

`
User.where(admin: true).map(&:email_addr)
User.where(admin: true).collect(&:email_addr)
User.where(admin: true).pluck(:email_addr)
`
```